# SQL Server Entity Framework SaveChanges('insert') Error in Piecemeal Partial Restored Database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-restore

We were troubling with moving large SQL Server database files from live system to test system. We found a piecemeal restoring solution. Because we only need latest records to test our system. We partitioned table by "id" column which is primary and identity.

It seemed it works with restoring 1 or 2 files over 10 files and with plain "select" and "insert" query.

But in application which we are using Entity Framework (EF) to query database 'insert' query had a problem.(Exception:One of the partitions of index '' for table 'table' partition ID... resides on a filegroup "...." that cannot be accessed because it is offline, restoring, or defunct. This may limit the query result.)

After checking the EF generated query

```
sp_executesql 'insert into table.... select id from table where @@rowcount>0 and Id=scope_idetity()'
```

I dig into the problem and I saw that 'scope identity' function needs extras files being restored.

My question is is there a different configuration to solve this issue or is there better solution fits our scenario in which needs large SQL file transfer to test system which only needs latest records.

Comment: The ideal solution is not having to rely on a live system to create your test system. Have a test database that is scripted and source controlled and seeded with generated data, problem solved.

Comment: It is not a good solution because backup database records is dependent to other independent systems.Scripted database is a complex solution which needs 'Id''s generated by other systems which are 'GUID' not an increasing int number.

Comment: This is probably more on-topic at [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I think your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.